# Issue with Mockito and JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring boot project that I'm migrating to Spring boot 2.
Some of my tests that where working with the previous version are failing with the new version.

The issue is easy to reproduce.

I create 2 Controller. In the first, I inject a Service. In the second, I inject a JpaRepository.

Now I create UnitTests for both this Controller.
For the second Controller, I mock the Repository. Everything works fine.
For the first Controller, I mock the Service. The test fail.
It seems to search to inject the Repository whereas it is not used in this Controller.

I create a very simple project to reproduce this behavior :
https://github.com/YLombardi/mockito-spring-jpa-issue

Is it my test that is wrong or a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the issue from the repo url you gave. If you notice the exception when you run `ControllerAUnitTests`, it says

`...UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllerB'...`

Now, why would spring try to load `controllerB` bean when you are running tests for `ControllerA`?

This is because you are using `SpringRunner` and default `mockMvc`. It loads whole spring context that means it will create beans of every component including `controllerB`.

To create the bean of `controllerB`, you need to have an instance of `JpaRepo`. So, just like you created mocked bean of `ServiceA` in `ControllerAUnitTests`, you need to create mocked bean for `JpaRepo` as well.

```
    @MockBean
    private ServiceA serviceA;

    // NOTE THIS BLOCK
    @MockBean
    private JpaRepo jpaRepo;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        doReturn("a").when(serviceA).getAString();
        mockMvc.perform(get("/a"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                // Test now runs but assert fails below, that you need to fix.
                .andExpect(view().name("aview"))
                .andExpect(content().string("a"));
    }
```

Comment: So I need to mock the JpaRepo in every test classes ? Even if It is not used in the Controller. It's seems weird. With the previous spring version, we needed to mock only the component that were injected in the class that is tested.

Comment: By default `MockMvc` is loaded with all context. If you just want to have context for a single controller, create standalone context using `MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup...`.

Comment: "*We needed to mock only the component that were injected in the class that is tested*"
- 
**True when you are running test with `MockitoJunitRunner`**.

Comment: Thanks, I understand my mistake. The new annotation @WebMvcTest does not replace the need to configure the MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controllerA).build();